# Is login with username or email safe and how to do it right?

Tags: php, authentication

I can see that people are starting to use login with username or email ( in the same field like here http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/2X0r ). I am wandering how safe this is ? I know that there were some other debates here in stack overflow considering if one should use only username or only email in combination with password. From my experience username was always better choice than email, but now we should allow users to use either ?

Also should I have UNIQUE constraint on username and/or email in my DB table with user data ?

And is it the right way to check for presence of whatever user typed in the first login field by executing one db query that is trying to find either username or email in DB ?

Comment: This is not a question of that option being _safe_. It does not matter what unique identifier you authenticate against. In the end it is just strings, one is as good as the other. There are other aspects one can start a discussion about, but security is none of them.

Comment: And _obviously_ you should have a unique constraint on the fields in your database you use to identify a user. How else do you want to decide which account to authenticate a login request against?

Comment: One could argue that you want to split logging in and account-recovery by not using an email address for both. Though I think the reason nowadays more places allow for registration with solely an email address is because of conversion. People experience picking a unique username as it being a hassle, so not having to do this will most likely increase the amount of people creating an  account on your platform.

Comment: Well if I have more than one same username, I am authenticating all of them with password. But I guess it may happen that two users have same usernames and passwords.

Comment: @offline It may not happen that two users have the same usernames. Clearly you don't want this to happen so you therefor do not allow this.

Comment: Honestly I have never saw someone using unique on username field. That way attacker can figure out that you have the particular username in the system, and he is half way there to figure out the all auth credentials he needs ( by brute force attacks or other ).

Comment: That is why I find using an email for authentication is a poor choice, had many examples of easy account cracking because of that.